# Apache camel Restlet producer cached

Tags: apache-camel

I am using camel 2.18.0 version.I am facing a issue while using restlet component in SEDA flow. Please find the route details below

```
from("timer://foo?repeatCount=1")
.to("http4://localhost:8080/pages")
.split(body())
.to("seda:pageConsumer");

from("seda:pageConsumer?concurrentConsumer=5")
.toD("restlet:${in.body}")
.process(enrich());
```

Details on route:

- "http4://localhost:8080/pages" this rest endpoint returns list of url 
  url= http://localhost:8080/data?page=1&size=5
- seda consumer is used for consuming each page parallel
- url "http://localhost:8080/data?page=1&size=5" streams the data (This is a rest endpoint and endpont does not send a list of data instead endpoint streams the data)
- restlet endpoint invokes the page url and streams the data.

Issue:

when seda endpoint receives 1st URL all is good i.e. "http://localhost:8080/data?page=1&size=5" rest endpoint is invoked by restlet and expected data is processed in route.

when seda endpoint receives 2nd URL i.e. 
"http://localhost:8080/data?page=2&size=5" , this where issue starts instead of invoking rest endpoint with "page=2&size=5" as query param, restlet use query param from 1st URL i.e. "page=1&size=5". and issue continues for rest of the urls.

upon debugging i found out that camel caches producer in ProducerCache
and producer is cached in a hashmap with endpoint uri as the key.

questions why does camel does not honour query param during caching? is there why to avoid the caching?

Please note i got the code working by changing the url to include page details which is ugly. Currently url looks like 
http://localhost:8080/data/page/2/size/5.

Comment: try disabling stream caching and test. `from("seda:pageConsumer?concurrentConsumer=5").noStreamCaching().toD("restlet:${in.body}").noStreamCaching()......`

Comment: What if you use stream option in splitter?

Answer (score 0):

If the restlet endpoint is calling the same http url (eg host:port) then it can be slightly better to use a plain `to` with this host:port as static, and then set a header with the dynamic part.

```
.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, constant("page1=&size=5"))
.to("http:xxxx")
```

Then the same endpoint/producer is reused and the header then includes the dynamic part with the query parameters.

There is also a header where you can set the context-path as well on `Exchange`.

If you keep using `toD` then you can adjust the size of the cache with the `cacheSize` option - its the same as on recipient list: http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html

Comment: Thanks for solution Claus Ibsen.
I am using restlet because rest service returns a stream. I did not find a way consume stream using http4 or http protocol.
Is there a way to set HTTP_QUERY part dynamically in restlet ? 
or is there a better way to consume a rest service which returns  stream in above route i.e. inside seda route.